# How does Health and Healing work in BattleBit Remastered

Tags: battlebit-remastered

I am new to Battlebit Remastered and am a bit confused on how the healing works as it seems to be different from most traditional FPS games (especially Battlefield 4 which it seems to draw a lot of inspiration from).

Every class in the game seems to have access to a few "Bandages", whereas the Medic class has access to a lot of "Bandages" as well as a "Medkit".

Sometimes while playing I may be downed and then revived by a Teammate, but my screen keeps a red vignette around it. Other times I am revived and then get a HUD pop-up that a Medic is healing me and the vignette goes away.

Can you **only** be healed by medics in this game? or are there other ways to get your health back (aside from respawning).

**How does Health and Healing work in BattleBit Remastered?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Medkits and bandages are different in what they actually do.

A Bandage is used for 2 things: reviving fallen teammates and stopping bleeding. Neither of which actually "heal" the target. Bleeding is a state of continual health loss until you eventually die, and reviving only brings the target back with 40%ish percent health.

A Medkit, on the flip side, cannot revive or stop bleeding. It is, however, the only item currently in the game that can heal. If you play as medic you can see teammate's missing health (the circles around them) and can use your medkit to heal 'em up. Other classes cannot heal and can only revive using their limited number of bandages.

Your health does not passively regenerate like other shooters and the only way you can guess your health is the red on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, this covers what I was looking for! I usually wait a day or two before accepting answers but this will likely be it. Feel free to tidy this comment once you have read it.